# determination of iis version in windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

I have read that windows 7 has iis version 7.5,[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609),but in my administrative tools I have 2 icon which are named iis manager and iis6 manager,what is my iis version? 6 or 7.5?
I have windows 7 ultimate,64 bit
why do I have iis 6 on windows 7?
I have installed iis 6 from turn features on or off,and I just had iis 6 option there,not 7 or 7.5!
Thanks in advance

Comment: why nobody answers me?please,I have to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

You get IIS 7.5 with windows 7.
The IIS manager is IIS 7.5 management console you want to use. 
The IIS 6 manager is used to help you remote connect and manage any IIS 6 servers if you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can **find it in Registry editor**

goto to Run and then type `regedit`

The `LOCAL MACHINE` Branch of registry contains the Version information for Windows 7.

The Starting Branch is in **(HKLM) HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \InetStp\ VersionString**

**Note:** The Spaces are for reading purposes.